# How to compare two multivariate datasets

Tags: distributions, python, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-distribution

I have two datasets consisting of 20 features, one set contains 50k records and the other 70k. I want to check if they are from the same population.
Datasets contain discrete features and the distribution is unknown, so far I've tried R [`crossmatch`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/crossmatch/versions/1.3-1) package but my dataset is too big for the package and would require about 150 GB of RAM.

Does anyone know how can I effectively compare two multivariate datasets?